# AWSGlueETL is dependent log4j security vulnerabilities `CVE-2021-44228`

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, log4j, aws-glue

Since had notified information for log4j security vulnerabilities, I researched if my applications were influenced. I discovered AWSGlueETL which is introduced by [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html) is dependent log4j security vulnerabilities. [pom.xml](https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/release/com/amazonaws/AWSGlueETL/1.0.0/AWSGlueETL-1.0.0.pom) include below definition.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Latest version `3.0.0` is also dependent same vulnerabilities. I would like to know if this problem will be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has provided an update on this, and looks like they are applying Amazon-developed Java hot patches to all affected services, please refer here for more info https://aws.amazon.com/security/security-bulletins/AWS-2021-006/

From the document:

> Responding to security issues such as this one shows the value of
> having multiple layers of defensive technologies, which is so
> important to maintaining the security of our customers’ data and
> workloads.
> We've taken this issue very seriously, and our world-class
> team of engineers has fully deployed the Amazon-developed Java hot
> patch available here to all AWS services. The hot patch updates the
> Java VM to disable the loading of the Java Naming and Directory
> Interface (JNDI) class, replacing it with a harmless notification
> message, which mitigates CVE-2021-44228 and CVE-2021-45046.  We will
> shortly complete our deployment of the updated Log4j library to all of
> our services.  More information about the Java hotpatch is available
> at
> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/open-source-hotpatch-for-apache-log4j-vulnerability/

Thanks